# Magento 2: how to get attribute additional options programmatically

Tags: magento2, attributes

In Magento 2.2.3, you can set additional options per each option of attribute:
[image]
[image]

How to programmatically access these properties? I tried:

```
$om =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productAttributeRepository = $om->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository');
$options = $productAttributeRepository->get('shoecolor')->getOptions();
foreach ($options as $option) {
    echo $option->getValue().' - '.$option->getLabel(). ' - '.$option->getMetaDescription().'<br>';
}
```

I know, we should avoid using ObjectManager, but wanted a fast way to see if I can pull this data, then I would create a Plugin for it.

```
$_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getAttributeDescription(), 'shoecolor')
```

Neither worked and I can't find anything useful on Google, only on how to retrieve options per attribute, nothing about additional options for options of attributes.

What I want to get is a Description and Image. If anyone can help me with this, I would appreciate it.

Comment: magento version?

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, it's 2.2.3.

Comment: Have you have any extension for those attribute settings

Comment: Not that I am aware of, thought that this is "out-of-the-box" Magento's functionality.

Comment: Just tried on clean Magento 2.2.3 and "Settings" buttons are not there, so it appears that this does come from an extension. Will have to look into which one causes this and look into their docs. Thanks for the tip!